# How to make macro create an alert when changing a value in the drop down list

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on an project that contains forms. Therefore users pick a specific type of form from the drop down list. How do you create an alert in excel using macro when a user picks certain type of form from the dropdown list. And after completing the form and before changing it I want to issue an alert saying that please make sure to Save the form. How is this done in excel.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What you made some prototype attempt?

Comment: Most common alerting the end user is `MsgBox()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can using event "Change" in Combobox

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

   MsgBox "Value changed"

End Sub
```

Or check value after change, like this

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

   If ComboBox1.Value = "ABC" Then

      MsgBox "Value changed"

   End If

End Sub
```

And about "alert Save the form", because I don't know your form, so I can't give you ideal.